# A non priority queue with insert priority

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, priority-queue

Google is giving me headaches with this search term.

I need a thread safe mechanism to achieve the following.
A thread safe list with insert priority over read.

I need to always be able to insert a message (let's say) to the queue (or whatever) and occasionally, be able to read.
So reading, cannot, ever, interfere with inserting.

Thanks.

EDIT:  Reading would also mean clearing the red part.

EDIT2: Maybe helpful, there is a single reader and a single writer.

EDIT3: Case scenario: 10 inserts per second for a period of 1 minute (or max possible using the hardware on which the software is on). Then a insert pause of 1 minute. Then 20 inserts (or max possible using the hardware on which the software is on) in 2 seconds for a period of 30 sec. Then a pause of 30 sec. Then the pause is used for max number of reads. I don't know if I am being clear enough. Obviously not. (PS: I don't know when the pause will occur, that is the problem). Max acc. delay for insert: the time for the Enqueue or Add method to finish.

ADDITIONAL: Could a ConcurrentDictionary with a AddOrUpdate with TryGetValue and TryRemove be used?

Comment: Without a limiting constraint, this queue could grow without bound and exhaust all memory, at which point insertion *must* fail or wait. So is there an actual upper limit on number of messages in the queue, or similar?

Comment: @sll what did you edit? (i see, tag)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever there is, but the important part here is insert priority. there, physically, cannot bee 'too much' messages in the queue.

Comment: @JJ_Jason click on the timestamp after _edited_ and see for yourself.

Comment: If the upper bound on number of messages is low, it should be simple to write a thead-safe queue based on a ring buffer. You'll usually end up with contention *between* readers, and *between* writers, but the two types of users don't tend to compete

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Would you mind elaborating a 'ring buffer' with the restrictions i need. how would i escape the read stall?

Comment: It seems you have a standard Producer/Consumer problem, no special constraints that warrant even considering lock-free solutions. 600/minute is very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct your queue as a linked list of objects. Keep a reference to the head and the tail of the queue. See below the pseudo code which roughly tells the idea

```
QueueEntity Head;
QueueEntity Tail

class QueueEntity
{
       QueueEntity Prev;
       QueueEntity Next;
       ...   //queue content; 
}

and then do this:

//Read
lock(Tail)
{
  //get the content
  Tail=Tail.Prev;
}

//Write
lock(Head)
{
   newEntity = new QueueEntity();
   newEntity.Next = Head ;
   Head.Prev = newEntity;
   Head = newEntity;
}
```

Here you have separate locks for reading and writing and they won't block each other unless there is only one entiry in your queue.

Comment: Sounds interesting, will check.